# $n\equiv n^{11} -n \pmod {11}$ Use properties of congruence to simplify.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$n \equiv n^{11} -n \pmod{11}$$

I am trying to figure out how these numbers came about $2^{11}-2\equiv(5)(5)(8)-2$

Where do the 5 & 8's come from??

Comment: I think you meant $2^{11}-2$ not $-1.$ Also, $5=2^4 \mod{11}$, so essentially the equation reads: $2^{11}=(2^4) (2^4) (2^3)= (5)(5)(8) \mod{11}$

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to determine some of the large numbers $7^{11} = 1977326743$ without using a calculator?

Comment: Do you mean how to determine them mod 11? Sure. You can do the same trick. For example, $7^2=49,$ which is $5 \mod{11},$ so $7^{11}=7(7^{10})=7(5^5)=7*5*5^4=7*5*3^2=7*5*(-2)=-70=77-70=7$

Comment: The idea is to treat 11 as 0, when you're working mod 11, and just add or subtract multiples of 11 where needed.

Comment: I meant how to obtain 1977326743, but I can see that is unnecessary using the congruence property. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, congruences are a lot of fun once you get the hang of it. Does take some getting used to, though.

Comment: Why don't use congruences to find the value of $7^{11}$-- only to find the remainder when divided by 11.  There may be some tricks to determine the value without a calculator but they are just tricks.  They aren't something studied.  ($7^2 = 100/2 - 1$ so $7^{11} = (100/2 - 1)^5 *7 = (10000000000/32 - 5*100000000/16 + 10*1000000/8 - 10*10000/4 + 5*100/2 - 1)7$.  Perhaps you can do something with that?  [better you than me...]).

Answer (score 2):

Do you know Fermat's little theorem, $n^p \equiv n \mod p$ for $n \not \equiv 0 \mod p$ and $p$ prime?

So $n^{11} \equiv n \mod 11$ if $n \not \equiv 0$.

So $n^{11} - n \equiv n - n \equiv 0 \mod 11$ if $n \not \equiv 0$.

So $n \equiv n^{11} - n \mod 11 \iff n \equiv 0 \mod 11$.